# Adding header to a scope title in TableViewController (Swift - Xcode)

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview

It's quite hard to explain but how can i add a header only to a scope button title instead of to the whole tableviewcontroller? For example, in the screenshots below, i only want the header "Most Interesting Booth" to appear when i tap on "Fun" A.K.A case 2 and not on "All" & "Top 10". Do comment if you are still unsure of what I'm saying. Thank you!

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
 switch selectedScope {
        case 0:
            postData.removeAll()
            postData2.removeAll()
            for data in tableDataArray {
                postData.append(data.boothName)

                let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                postData2.append(value)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()

        case 1:
            postData.removeAll()
            postData2.removeAll()
            let sortedTableData = tableDataArray.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })
            for data in sortedTableData {
                postData.append(data.boothName)

                let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                postData2.append(value)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        case 2:
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
                let view = UIView()
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                return view
            }
            postData.removeAll()
            postData2.removeAll()
            let sortedTableData = tableDataArray.sorted(by: { $0.boothRating > $1.boothRating })
            for data in sortedTableData {
                postData.append(data.boothName)

                let value = String(describing: data.boothRating)
                postData2.append(value)
            }
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        default:
            break

        }
        tableView.reloadData()

    }
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to do it in this way, you can use an enum to have a cleaner reference when you update your table view.

**Create an enum, for example:**

```
enum BoothScope: Int {
    case all
    case top
    case fun
}
```

**Add a BoothScope var:**

```
var selectedBoothScope: BoothScope = .all
```

And you can manage it in this way:

```
 func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
     guard selectedBoothScope == BoothScope(rawValue: selectedScope) else { return }

     switch selectedBoothScope {
            case .all:
            //...
            case .top:
            //...
            case .fun:
            //remove this:
            func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
                let view = UIView()
                view.backgroundColor = UIColor.orange
                return view
            }
            //...
```

**And finally:**

(if you prefer you can use the delegate func `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, 
 viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?)`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return "yourTitle"
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView,heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    if selectedBoothScope == .fun {
        return 30
    }
    return 0
}
```